# react-native Error building DependencyGraph

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native

After running `react-native run-android` I get the following error, I have no idea what to do from here as I installed everything the standard way using npm i

```
Error building DependencyGraph:
Error: Naming collision detected: /Users/guerilla/Code/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/lib/CSSCore.js collides with /Users/guerilla/Code/ReactNative/node_modules/react/node_modules/fbjs/lib/CSSCore.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can work around that

1. It seems npm 3 handles duplicate dependencies much better than old versions of npm so delete your node_modules folder, upgrade to npm 3 and the run npm i again, this should solve the problem
2. Manually install fbjs on the top level, ie add it as a dependency in you package.json file and manually delete all occurences of fbjs in other modules so they all use the same one on the top level

Comment: thank you for fast response, I will tr it immediately